# jQuery: wrapAll() span elements while retaining white space

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have a text with each word wrapped with a `span` element to make them clickable. I want to be able to highlight a section of the text by clicking the first and the last words to be highlighted and then click a separate button to execute the highlighting (i.e. wrap every word between and including the first and the last words selected). A comment will also be added after the highlighted section. I've made progress and have gotten up to this part:

The HTML:

```
<div id="textbox">
<span>Foo</span> <span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> 
<span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> 
<span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> <span>foo</span> <span>foo</span>.
</div>
<input id="commentbox" placeholder="Type your comment here"> 
<button id="exechighlight" value="Highlight">
```

The JavaScript:

```
$('#textbox > span').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#exechighlight').click(function(){
if($('#commentbox').val() !== '') {
  $('.selected').filter(":last").after(' <span class="comment">' + $('#commentbox').val() + '</span>');
} else {
  $('.selected').filter(':last').after(' <span class="comment">Default comment</span>');
}
$('.selected').filter(":first").nextUntil('.comment').andSelf().wrapAll('<span class="highlight">');
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$('#commentbox').val('');
});
```

I can wrap thing just fine, but `wrapAll()` doesn't seem to retain the spaces between the wrapped `span` elements. I've tried with CSS, to no avail:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: #f00; 
  white-space: pre-wrap; 
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
}
```

How to proceed? I need to be able to undo the highlighting as well, i.e. to unwrap the `<span class='highlight'>` and retain the original spacing.

Comment: You'd make it **much** easier to help you if you turned those code blocks into a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'll make sure to remember that the next time I need to post a question!

Answer (score 0):

> but `wrapAll()` doesn't seem to retain the spaces between the wrapped `span` elements

As indeed it shouldn't, because they aren't in the jQuery set you said you wanted to wrap. `nextUntil` only looks at elements, not text nodes.

You'll need to build the jQuery set yourself, including the text nodes between the spans. See comments:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  // Find the selected span
  var sel = $(".selected");
  
  // Find the comment span (raw, no jQuery wrapper)
  var comment = sel.siblings(".comment")[0];
  
  // Gather up all nodes (including text nodes) following it, up until the comment element
  var node = sel[0];
  var nodes = [];
  while (node && node !== comment) {
    nodes.push(node);
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
  
  // Disregard final text node if any
  if (nodes.length && nodes[nodes.length - 1].nodeType === 3) {
    --nodes.length;
  }
  
  // Get a jQuery set for them, and wrap it
  $(nodes).wrapAll("<span class='wrapper'></span>");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="selected">one</span>
  <span>two</span>
  <span>three</span>
  <span class="comment">The comment</span>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** method doesn't include the `textnode`.  You need to get the `textNode` also with help of **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** method in jQuery.

```js
$('#textbox > span').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#exechighlight').click(function() {
  if ($('#commentbox').val() !== '') {
    $('.selected').filter(":last").after(' <span class="comment">' + $('#commentbox').val() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('.selected').filter(':last').after(' <span class="comment">Default comment</span>');
  }
  getAllNode($('.selected').filter(":first").nextUntil('.comment').andSelf()).wrapAll('<span class="highlight">');
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $('#commentbox').val('');
});

// method for getting the element which also includes textnode
function getAllNode($sel) {
  // get the first element from selector
  var $first = $sel.first(),
    // get the last element from selector
    $last = $sel.last(),
    // flag variable for filter method
    match = false;
  // get all nodes includes text node of it's parent
  return $sel.parent().contents().filter(function() {
    // filter out element eleemnt in between the first and last including the first and last
    if ($(this).is($first) || $(this).is($last)) {
      match = !match;
      return true;
    }
    return match;
  });
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #f00;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textbox">
  <span>Foo</span>  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span> 
  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span> 
  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span>  <span>foo</span>.
</div>
<input id="commentbox" placeholder="Type your comment here">
<button id="exechighlight" value="Highlight">
```